# How To Mark a String in a File?

Tags: java

I have a text file. It is designed as following:

```
#1{1,12,345,867}
#2{123, 3243534, 2132131231} 
#3{234, 35345}
#4{}
```

...
(at the end of an each entry stands "\n")

That is an example. In fact my strings #number{number,number,...,number} could be really long...

Here is a template of a constructor of a class which works with this file:

```
public Submatrix(String matrixFilePath, int startPos, int endPos) throws FileNotFoundException{

}
```

As you can see submatrix is determined by startPos and endPos numbers of strings of a matrix.

My question is : "How could I count strings to reach the right one?"
My file can contain billions of strings. Should I use LineNumberReader->readLine() billions times?????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer would be yes, you read billions of lines using `readLine`, unless you think it's worth the trouble using either

- the strategy outlined by GregS, that is, estimating the line length and using that to start reading somewhere near the correct line, or
- you use a seperate index, either at the start of the file or in a separate file which is very predictable and is something like

  ```
  0000001 000000001024
  0000002 000000001064
  0000003 000000002010
  ```

  That is, line number and starting position of that line in bytes in a strictly defined fashion which makes it possible to determine the position of the index by something like:

  I want to read line 3, so I find the position of line 3 by going to position (3-1) * 20,
  and read  `0000003 000000002010`, parse that and know that line 3 is at byte position 2010, seek that position and start reading.

  Calculating or maintaining the index might not be easy if it's in the main data file, as it would mean that you precalculate positions before you actually write the file. I think I would use a seperate index file and either calculate indices during writing, or have a seperate utility to create a index file given a data file.

**EDIT** Added example code to demonstrate my proposal

I have made a smallish Python script which reads a data file and creates an index file. The index file contains the position of a line in the data file and is designed to be easily searchable.

This example script has index formatting of 06d, which is good enough for 999.999 line data files, for you it might have to be adjusted (don't forget INDEX_LENGTH). It creates an index file, and uses that index file to read a given line out of the data file (for demonstration purposes; you would use java for that part:)

The script is called like:

```
python create_index.py data.txt data.idx 3
```

my example data file is:

```
#1{1,12,345,867}
#2{123, 3243534, 2132131231}
#3{234, 35345}
#4{}
```

and the script itself is:

```
import sys

# Usage: python this_script.py datafile indexfile lineno
# indexfile will be overwritten
# lineno is the data line which will be printed using the
# index file, as a demonstration
datafilename= sys.argv[1]
indexfilename = sys.argv[2]
lineno = int(sys.argv[3])

# max 999999 lines in this format
format = "%06d\n"
INDEX_LENGTH = 6+1 # +1 for newline


def create_indexfile():
        indexfile = open(indexfilename, "wB")
        # Print index of first line
        indexfile.write(format % 0)

        f = open(datafilename, "rB")
        line = f.readline()
        while len(line) > 0:
                indexfile.write( format % f.tell() )
                line = f.readline()
        f.close()
        indexfile.close()

# Retrieve the data of 1 line in the data file
# using the index file
def get_line():
        linepos = INDEX_LENGTH * (lineno - 1)

        indexfile = open(indexfilename, "rB")
        indexfile.seek(linepos)
        datapos = int(indexfile.readline())
        indexfile.close()

        datafile = open(datafilename, "rB")
        datafile.seek(datapos)
        print datafile.readline()
        datafile.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
        create_indexfile()
        get_line()
```

The index file needs to be rebuild after a change in the data file. You can verify if you read the right data by comparing your line number from the data read (#3{...}) with the input line number, so it's fairly safe.

Whether you choose to use it or not, I think the example is pretty clear and easy.

Comment: I'm not sure if I could use this strategy with such an information file. Function seek(arg) works with "long" argument, so that I only can use 2^63-1 symbols. But If I have to read the last string and there are billions of large strings, I think there would much more symbols... What to do?

Comment: Well, may be I took the wrong strategy. My task is following: I must program the algorithm of four russians to multiply 2 boolean matrice. These matrice are really huge(as I sayd, billions of large strings)! I chose the representation. where numbers between {} show places where 1s stay. According to this algorithm I need to add two such strings(these strings locate in a file). I want to search two strings then save a part of each of them in a buffer(ArrayList<Integer>), then add these parts by a certain rule, then save the result to a special result-file. So I need  to search these two strings

Comment: My be there is another way to represent a matrix, which will help to search needed strings???

Comment: @Dmitry If it fits into the file you can address it with a long. 2^63 is about 9.22337204 × 1018 bytes, so I can't imagine that not being enough at this moment. Second, I don't think string representation is the way to go; it's better to use binary representations, or a binary file. That would keep the file smaller and parsing faster. Personally I think I would ask a question about java matrix libraries, which one is best, with a requirement of file IO capabilities.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. But would I know the number of the string? Also, using strings with numbers I try to decrease the size of the matrix.

Comment: @Dmitry I actually meant the numbers between bracers, should they really be strings? The way you describe it suggests a sparse matrix to me, and there are standard ways to handle those.

Comment: So, you suggest to represent them like binary numbers? That way, how could I save binary data with int or string (can you, please, give an example)? 
May be I should use serialization in some way? But if there is an effective method to deserialize what I need?

Comment: @Dmitry added example code how to create and use an index file.

Comment: @Dmitry could you give me some info ion the data structure in the software which makes the datafile? That would determine whether Serialization (which I was thinking of) is practical. My other thought would be *memory-mapped IO*.

Comment: Oh, I realised. I don't need the part #number to represent my matrix. If I make a map according to your post I will only need to define the startPos for a concrete "string" in the map-file. 
Thank you for your answer!!!

Comment: =) firstly posted and the looked at your example

Comment: Could you, please, specify the question about datafiles

Comment: @Dmitry That would only be relevant if you start using serialization; there the types of data (int, long, Integer, Long, List or int[] and such) would be of importance. If you keep this format (with or without file numbers) that is not important.

Comment: I added the implementation of some classes which could possibly be serialized (if it has any sence)

Comment: @Dmitry I've seen the datafiles and a row is basically a List of Integers. You could use the ObjectOutputStream / ObjectInputStream to get a smaller data file, but probably worse performance. I also checked the FileChannel API for memory mapped IO, but that would required (de)serialization into ByteBuffers and keeping an index file for the different lines. The files would probably be smaller, but the code complexity larger. At this stage I would just check how the current String based code performs with the index file.

Answer (score 5):

I would be tempted to read each line sequentially until I reached the desired line. However, since the lines are numbered *in the file* and delimited with newlines you can treat the file as random access and employ various strategies. For example, you get use a variant of binary search to quickly find the starting line. You can estimate the average line length from the first N lines and then try to make a more accurate guess as to the starting location, and so on.

Comment: Didn't realise the lines were numbered... If that is the case, this looks like a good solution indeed. However, if reading each line does not give big performance issues, I would not bother...

Comment: One thing to note is that anything with redundant information like this becomes quite brittle and hard to work with - if you add an extra line into the file anywhere but the end, you need to renumber the remainder. That may not be a problem in this particular case, but it's worth considering.

Comment: @Fortega: I agree completely, I would avoid it if at all possible. You'd have to read "backwards", which for me would be confusing with unexpected corner cases (like running off the beginning of file!) and thus bug-prone, plus I don't think any underlying buffering strategies assume you'll read backwards, so your actual performance would be less than you might expect unless you wrote a lot of custom code (MySymmetricBufferedReader)... a whole lot of buggy yechhh will creep in.

Comment: Well, I always add strings to the end of a file.

Answer (score 1):

@extraneon

This is the class I want to use to represent a string #number{number, number,...}

```
package logic;

public class DenominatedBinaryRow{
private int sn;
private BinaryRow row;

public DenominatedBinaryRow(int sn, BinaryRow row){
    this.sn = sn;
    this.row = row;
}

public DenominatedBinaryRow plus(int sn, DenominatedBinaryRow addend){
    return new DenominatedBinaryRow(sn, this.row.plus(addend.row));
}

public int getSn(){
    return this.sn;
}

public BinaryRow getRow(){
    return this.row;
}

public boolean equals(Object obj){
    DenominatedBinaryRow res = (DenominatedBinaryRow) obj;
    if (this.getSn() == res.getSn() && this.getRow().equals(res.getRow())){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

 }
```

May be it would be efficient to serialize it, instead of converting the BinaryRow (it's implementation goes below) to a string?
If I serialize many instances of it to a file, how will I deserialize the necessary string (necessary instance) back? (Hope, I understood your question correctly)

```
package logic;

import java.util.*;

public class BinaryRow {
private List<Integer> row;

public BinaryRow(){
    this.row = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}

public List<Integer> getRow(){
    return this.row;
}

public void add(Integer arg){
    this.getRow().add(arg);
}

public Integer get(int index){
    return this.getRow().get(index);
}

public int size(){
    return this.getRow().size();
}


public BinaryRow plus(BinaryRow addend){
    BinaryRow result = new BinaryRow();

    //suppose, rows are already sorted (ascending order)
    int i = this.size();
    int j = addend.size();
    while (i > 0 && j > 0)
        if (this.get(this.size() - i) < addend.get(addend.size() - j)){
            result.add(this.get(this.size() - i));
            i--;
        }
        else if (this.get(this.size() - i) > addend.get(addend.size() - j)){
            result.add(addend.get(addend.size() - j));
            j--;
        }
        else{
            result.add(this.get(this.size() - i));
            i--;
            j--;
        }

    if (i > 0){
        for (int k = this.size() - i; k < this.size(); k++)
            result.add(this.get(k));
    }
    if (j > 0){
        for (int k = addend.size() - j; k < addend.size(); k++)
            result.add(addend.get(k));
    }

    return result;
}

public boolean equals(Object obj){
    BinaryRow binRow = (BinaryRow) obj;
    if (this.size() == binRow.size()){
        for (int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++){
            if (this.getRow().get(i) != binRow.getRow().get(i)) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public long convertToDec(){
    long result = 0;
    for (Integer next : this.getRow()) {
        result += Math.pow(2, next);
    }

    return result;
}
```

}

Comment: @Dmitry you already seem to have a pretty hefty serialization with the pow() method. An easy size optimization would be to write the String numbers radix 36 (see Long.toString(long i, int radix) and Long.valueOf(String s, int radix) to make the numbers a bit shorter. Just like Hex but more so :) 

As a side note, equals usually checks the type (instanceof) before castingto prevent casting exceptions, and you usually also make a hashCode if you implement equals.

I do love your choice for composition with List in stead of just inheriting.

Comment: Ok, but how will I work with such data? I mean how will I count necessary bytes to use them in an index-file? Or that is a different variant of realization?

Comment: You now write a number as 12345, then that same number would be 9ix. The data format would then be {9ix, ...}. The index file would be exactly the same format (different values of course), but writing and reading the data file should use Long.toString(number, _radix_) and Long.valueOf(string, _radix_) in stead of default toString(number) and valueOf(string) with default radix 10.

Answer (score -1):

I am affraid you have to get to the x-th line, you will have to call readLine() x times.
This means reading all the data until you reach this line. Every character could be a line end, so there is no way going to the x-th line without reading every character before this line.

Comment: Didn't see the lines were numbered, so other solutions might be better for you...